# Intel Smart Sound Technology - No sound - Dummy Ouput

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have bought a new laptop and installed a GNU/Linux distro along with Windows 10, the problem I am having is that I have no audio, the audio does not work with any distro that I tried while on Windows the audio works fine, I would appreciate it a lot if someone can help me to fix the audio.

A little more information about my problem:

> Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Release: 20.04 Codename: focus

> - headphones don't work either
> - apparently my sound card uses: intel SST (intel smart sound technology)
> - Fast start up of windows is disabled.
> - Output Device is "Dummy Output"
> - Kernel version: 5.15.0-41-generic (i tried installing version 5.18, it didn't work)
> - Output of "aplay -l" is :

```
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

> - Output of "inxi -A" is:

```
    Audio:
      Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio 
      driver: snd_hda_intel 
      Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-41-generic
```

> - Output of "cat /proc/asound/cards" is :

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1218000 irq 130
```

> - Output of "hwinfo --sound" is :

```
 17: PCI 1f.3: 0401 Multimedia audio controller                  
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.0bu6GdcFr73
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Device Name: "Onboard - Sound"
  Model: "Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x9dc8 "Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1c6c 
  SubDevice: pci 0x122a 
  Revision: 0x30
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xa1218000-0xa121bfff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xa1000000-0xa10fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 130 (273 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00009DC8sv00001C6Csd0000122Abc04sc01i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

> - Output of "lspci":

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics 655 (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation BayHubTech Integrated SD controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dea (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 30)
00:1a.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc4 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9da8 (rev 30)
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dab (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, or some other Linux distro? If Ubuntu, please edit your question to add the version number. sound should work "out of the box," and if you're using some other distro, troubleshooting steps may be different than Ubuntu. Please note that this site is only for official Ubuntu flavors, other Linux questions can be asked on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hello, I am using Ubuntu, this version

Description: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focus
No LSB modules are available.